Does Jena have utils to generate UnionGraph with Node.ANY?
I am want to union two RDF Graph g1 and g2.
g1 has a triple a b c, g2 has a triple a b d, and I want to "union" them to a triple a b Node.ANY. Are there some other utils to make it?
I use Union(g1, g2), but it will straightly generate a graph with a b c and a b d.

You can achieve that with SPARQL Construct queries.
You need one query for each case.
e.g.
Here is the case where the subject and predicate are the same:
PREFIX  ex:   <http://example.com/>
construct {?s ?p ex:any}
where {
?s ?p ?o
} group by ?s ?p

There are only a handful of cases.

Node.ANY is the wild card marker and isn't a legal RDF term. There is machinery for processing graphs but nothing that cares out the task described.
If you want a marker, I suggest you create your own URI (maybe a blank node if blank nodes don't appear in the data) and treat this as a process to create the union graph to your needs by copying g1, then adding triples from g2 testing whether to change the outcome graph, deleting a b c and putting in a b myANY.
It'll need to consider what to do about mathcing overlaps in the g1 graph e.g. a b c, a b z similarly in g2 - do they become myANY?
There are a few places where Node.ANY is unlikely to work in practical terms such as graph indexing. But the key problem is Graph.find(s,p,o) where a ANY is wildcard and will not match a Node.ANY in the data.
